# Calculating the probability of an event over multiple subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm struggling on the following problem:

> You are given N boxes indexed from 1 to N.  Each box contains either
> no coins or one coin.  The number of empty boxes and the number of
> boxes with one coin are denoted by n0 and n1, respectively.  You take
> a random subset of the boxes where each subset has the same same
> probability to be selected.  The empty set and the set itself are
> considered a subset.
>
> Given n0 and n1, what is the probability that the total number of
> coins in the random subset is even?
>
> Constraint: N = n0 + n1 < 100000
>
> #### EXAMPLES
>
> 1
>
> - Input: n0 = 1, n1 = 0
> - Output: 1.0
> - Explanation: There are two subsets: [] and [0]. Both of them have an even sum.
>
> 2
>
> - Input: n0 = 0, n1 = 2
> - Output: 0.5
> - Explanation: There are four subsets: [], [1], [1], and [1, 1]. The sum of [] and [1,1] is even.

So far I attempted an implementation in Python 3.8, but I think it works ok, but it takes very long to compute for larger numbers.

```
prob = 0

n0 = 1
n1 = 4

for j in range(0, n1+1):
        if (j % 2 == 0):
            prob += comb(n1, j)

total_prob = (2**n0 * prob) / (2 ** (n0+n1))
total_prob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another proof that if $n_1 >0$, then the number of subsets containing an even number of coins is the same as the number of subsets containing an odd number of coins.

Let's say $N_{even}$ is the number of subsets containing an even number of coins, and $N_{odd}$ is the number containing an odd number of coins.

How many subsets are there that contain exactly $k$ coins, where $0 \le k \le n_1$?  There are $\binom{n_1}{k}$ ways to select the boxes containing coins, and then we can throw in any subset of the empty boxes, which can be done in $2^{n_0}$ ways.  So all together, there are
$$\binom{n_1}{k}2^{n_0}$$
subsets that contain exactly $k$ coins.

So
$$\begin{align} N_{even}-N_{odd} &= \sum_{k \text{ even}} \binom{n_1}{k}2^{n_0} - \sum_{k \text{ odd}} \binom{n_1}{k}2^{n_0} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n_1} (-1)^k \binom{n_1}{k}2^{n_0} \\
&= 2^{n_0} \sum_{k=0}^{n_1} (-1)^k \binom{n_1}{k}
\end{align}$$
But
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n_1} (-1)^k \binom{n_1}{k} = 0$$
because by the Binomial Theorem,
$$0 = (1-1)^{n_1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n_1} (-1)^k \binom{n_1}{k}$$
so
$$ N_{even}-N_{odd} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

If $n_1=0$ then the answer is $1$ because all choices have no coins (and $0$ is even).

For $n_1>0$ the answer is $\frac 12$.

Proof:

First note that, if $n_1$ is odd, the answer is $\frac 12$ because either the chosen set or its complement (but not both), have evenly many coins.

Now suppose that $n_1$ is even.

Choose a coin $C$. We divide the subsets into two types, according to whether $C$ is an element or not. Of course there are $2^{N-1}$ subsets of each type.

If you choose  from the subsets without $C$ then we are in the odd case, as we are, effectively, choosing a subset from $n$ boxes that contain $n_1-1$ coins,  and we are done.

If you choose from the subsets with $C$ then the problem reduces to the case of $n_1-1$ coins as we are choosing a subset of the $n-1$ boxes which collectively hold $n_1-1$ coins.  As $n_1-1$ is odd, we are done.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! empirically I indeed come to the same conclusion, under the hypothesis that my algorithm implementation is correct

Comment: What does the code yield in the other case?  Does it look like there is a simple pattern or not?

Comment: The second question seems far less trivial, but after playing with the number, some patterns appear in the results (similar result are given when changing the numbers; eg. n0= 10, n1= 700, n2= 100 gives the same result (0.11111) as n0=11, n1=600, n2= 201); thus there must be some way of simplifying the calculation

Comment: I moved the second part of the problem in another topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853899/optimise-complexity-of-combinatoric-algorithm-2