# Optimise complexity of combinatoric algorithm (2)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to find a way to optimise the calculation for the following problem:

> You are given N boxes indexed from 1 to N. Each box contains 0, 1, or 2 coins.  The number of boxes with 0, 1, or 2 coins are denoted n0, n1, and n2 respectively. You take a random subset of the boxes where each subset has the same same probability to be selected. The empty set and the set itself are considered a subset.
> What is the probability that the total number
> of coins in a random subset is divisible by 3.
>
> Constraint: N = n0 + n1 + n2 < 100000
>
> #### EXAMPLES
>
> 1
>
> - Input: n0 = 0, n1 = 1, n2 = 0
> - Output: 0.5
> - Explanation: There are two subsets: [] and [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852436/calculating-the-probability-of-an-event-over-multiple-subset/). Only the sum of [] is a multiple of 3.
>
> 2
>
> - Input: n0 = 0, n1 = 2, n2 = 0
> - Output: 0.25
> - Explanation: There are four subsets: [], [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852436/calculating-the-probability-of-an-event-over-multiple-subset/), [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852436/calculating-the-probability-of-an-event-over-multiple-subset/), and [1, 1]. Only the sum of [] is a multiple of 3.
>
> 3
>
> - Input: n0 = 1, n1 = 1, n2 = 1
> - Output: 0.5
> - Explanation: There are eight subsets and the following four have a sum that is a multiple of 3: [], [0], [1, 2], and [0, 1, 2].

My implementation in Python 3.8:

```
prob = 0

for j in range(0, n1+1):
    for k in range(0, n2+1):
        if j == k:
            prob += comb(n1, j) * comb(n2, k)

        elif (j % 3 == 0) & (k % 3 == 0):
            prob += comb(n1, j) * comb(n2, k)

total_prob = (2**n0 * prob) / (2 ** (n0+n1+n2))
return total_prob
```

The result doesn't seem trivial, but after playing with the number, some patterns appear : similar result are given when changing the numbers; eg. `n0= 10, n1= 700, n2= 100` gives the same result (`0.11111`) as `n0=11, n1=600, n2= 201`; thus there must be some way of simplifying the calculation

This question is related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852436/calculating-the-probability-of-an-event-over-multiple-subset/).

I tried to implement the solution proposed by Mike, but I must have made something wrong as the result is not correct, and it takes ages to compute:

```
def p_x_equals_i(n1, n2, i):
    
    y_n1 = n1 // 2 
    y_n2 = n2 // 2
    z_n1 = n1 // 2 + (n1 % 2) 
    z_n2 = n2 // 2 + (n2 % 2)
    
    prob = 0
    
     ## i equals 0
    
    if n1 == 1 and n2 ==0 and i == 0:
        return 0.5
    
    if n1 == 0 and n2 == 0 and i == 0:
        return 1
    
    if n1 == 0 and n2 ==1 and i == 0:
        return 0.5
    
    if n1 == 1 and n2 ==1 and i == 0:
        return 0.5
    
    ## i equals 1
    
    if n1 == 1 and n2 ==0 and i == 1:
        return 0
    
    if n1 == 0 and n2 == 0 and i == 1:
        return 0
    
    if n1 == 0 and n2 ==1 and i == 1:
        return 0.5
    
    if n1 == 1 and n2 ==1 and i == 1:
        return 0.25
    
    if i == 0:
        return p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) * p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) +\
            p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1) * \
                    ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1))) + \
             ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1))) *\
                p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1)


    if i == 1:
        return  p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) * p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1) +\
            p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1) *  p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) +\
            ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1))) *\
                ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1)))

    else:
        print('error')       

def recursive(n1, n2):
    y_n1 = n1 // 2 
    y_n2 = n2 // 2
    z_n1 = n1 // 2 + (n1 % 2) 
    z_n2 = n2 // 2 + (n2 % 2)
    
    return p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) * p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) +\
            p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1) * \
                    ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1))) + \
             ( 1 - (p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 0) + p_x_equals_i(y_n1, y_n2, 1))) *\
                p_x_equals_i(z_n1, z_n2, 1)
```

UPDATE 2 (Solution):
Here is the code I come up with, following the 2nd answer from Mike. Thanks a lot for the help again!

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
import numpy as np

def p(n):
    A = np.array([[0.5, 0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0], [0, 0.5, 0.5]])
    p0 = [1, 0, 0]
    return matrix_power(A, n).dot(p0)

def q(n):
    B = np.array([[0.5, 0.5, 0],[0, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0, 0.5]])
    q0 = [1, 0, 0]
    return matrix_power(B, n).dot(q0)

def f(n1, n2):
    pn1 = p(n1)
    qn1 = q(n1)
    qn2 = q(n2)
    
    return pn1[0] * qn2[0] + pn1[1] * qn2[2] + pn1[2] * qn2[1]
```

Comment: Good start! Check your base cases for i = 1, that should fix the wrong values. The reason you code is so slow is because you have too many recursive calls. It is the same reason that the program to compute the Fibonacci numbers with the recursive call f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) is so slow.

Comment: hey Mike, thanks for your answer but i dont get it in terms of computing time; if the recursive way of calculating the value is slower than my initial algorithm, is it worth implementing ?!

Comment: It can be done quicker! For example, you do not need a recursive call to compute P(Y = 2), you should instead use one minus the sum of the other two. But it requires more fixes for a true speedup. I’m sorry, this was more difficult than I anticipated.

Comment: However, you may be pleased to know there is an O(1) solution! Not quite, but almost. Try computing with n2 = n0 = 0, and n1 = 1,2,3,... until you see the pattern.

Comment: I should add, it helps to compute $P(X \equiv 1)$ and  $P(X \equiv 2)$ as well to see the pattern. You see a similar pattern when n1 = 0 and n2 grows, and can then combine those two observations into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a second answer since it is different enough.

Let $p(n,0)$ be the probability that the number of coins is congruent to $0\pmod 3$  when there are $n$ boxes with one coin, and zero boxes with $0$ or $2$ coins. Similarly, let $p(n,1)$ and $p(n,2)$ be the probability that the number of chosen coins is $\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $\equiv 2\pmod 3$ in this scenario. By considering whether or not box number $n$ is chosen, you get the recursion
$$
p(n,0)=\tfrac12p(n-1,0)+\tfrac12p(n-1,2)\\
p(n,1)=\tfrac12p(n-1,1)+\tfrac12p(n-1,0)\\
p(n,2)=\tfrac12p(n-1,2)+\tfrac12p(n-1,1)\\
$$
Now, let $\vec p(n)$ be the column vector $[p(n,0)\quad p(n,1)\quad p(n,2)]^T$. The above equations can be summarized as a matrix equation
$$
\vec p(n) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac12&0&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12&0\\0&\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}\vec p(n-1)
$$
Iterating this recursion, and letting $A$ be the matrix of $\frac12$ and $0$ above, you get that
$$
\vec p(n)=A^n\vec p(0)
$$
Therefore, if you can compute the matrix power $A^n$ quickly, then you can find $\vec p(n)$ quickly. You can compute $A^n$ in $O(\log n)$ time using exponentiation by squaring.

So far, we have solve the special case where $n_2=0$. Letting $q(n,0)$ be the probability the number of coins is $\equiv 0\pmod 3$ when there are $n$ boxes with $2$ coins and nothing else, similarly for $q(n,1)$ and $q(n,2)$, a similar scheme allows you to compute the vector $\vec q(n)$ quickly. Finally, letting $f(n_1,n_2)$ be the probability you desire when there are $n_1$ one-coin boxes and $n_2$ two-coin boxes, you get
$$
f(n_1,n_2) = p(n_1,0)q(n_2,0)+p(n_1,1)q(n_2,2)+p(n_1,2)q(n_2,1).
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer mike, i updated my question with an implementation of your solution, but it seems I get results still different with my initial algo.
Also in your last equation, is it 

f(n_1,n_2) = p(n_1,0)q(**n_2**,0)+p(n_1,1)q(n_2,2)+p(n_1,2)q(n_2,1) ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. OK, my algorithm is correct, and your initial algorithm is wrong. Two problems; there is no need to do the $j=k$ case, since that is counted for by `j%3==0 & k%3==0`. More importantly, you also need to account for `j%3==1 & k%3 == 1` and `j%3==2 & k%3 == 2`. For example, if you select $5$ boxes with one coin and $8$ boxes with two coins, then the number of coins is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: With these extra cases, your result for the original program in the cases you asked about should increase from `0.11111` to `0.33333`, because you were only counting one third of the event. The results are still the same, and this is no coincidence; when the number of boxes is large, the number of coins is approximately equally likely to be any of the three values $\pmod 3$.

Comment: thanks a lot @Mike for all your precious help on this problem! Yeah I figured out also that the solution should converge to 1/3. Really appreciate you help!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is roughly linear in $n_1,n_2$. We can do this logarithmically in $n_1,n_2$ as follows.

Let $X_{n_1,n_2}$ be the random variable equal to the remainder $\pmod 3$ of the number of coins when there are $n_1$ boxes with one coin, and $n_2$ with $2$. Note that $n_0$ is not referenced, since it does not affect the probability distribution. The probability distribution of $X_{n_1,n_2}$ is described by three numbers summing to $1$, or more succinctly by two of those numbers $P(X_{n_1,n_2}\equiv 0\pmod 3)$ and $P(X_{n_1,n_2}\equiv 1\pmod 3)$.

We can compute these probabilities recursively as follows. Imagine splitting the one coin boxes into two roughly equal halves, one red and one blue, and same for the two coin boxes. Let $Y$ be the number of blue coins selected, and let $Z$ be the number of red coins selected, so that $X_{n_1,n_2}=Y+Z$. Then using $\equiv$ to mean "congruent modulo $3$", we have
$$
P(X_{n_1,n_2}\equiv 0)=P(Y\equiv 0)P(Z\equiv 0)+P(Y\equiv 1)P(Z\equiv 2)+P(Y\equiv 2)P(Z\equiv 1)\\
P(X_{n_1,n_2}\equiv 1)=P(Y\equiv 0)P(Z\equiv 1)+P(Y\equiv 1)P(Z\equiv 0)+P(Y\equiv 2)P(Z\equiv 2)
$$
This immediately leads to a recursive algorithm, since $Y$ and $Z$ are similar random variables described by parameters which are half the size.

Comment: hey @Mike thanks a lot for your answer. I kinda get a grasp of your solution theoretically, but when it comes to actually implement it, I'm a bit lost...
"splitting the one coin boxes into two roughly equal halves", so i guess i should implement something that halve the n1 and n2, but how to handle the odd numbers? cheers

Comment: also, out of your two final equation, the first one is not enough to calculate the probability that the total number of coins in a random subset is divisible by 3 ?

Comment: @Roger You only need the first equation to answer the question, but you need both equations for the recursion you work. I can add more detail in a couple of days

Comment: thanks for the clarification @mike, I updated the question with a tentative of implementation of your solution